# mysql taking 100% of CPU

Tags: mysql, cpu

I had a problem with my VPS like a week ago, and I had to completely reinstall it for it to work. It worked, but just for a while.

Everything was alright until now, I really don't know what the problem is.

The mysql error log has errors about `maxrequestworkers`, so we increased the max workers, but that didn't do anything, still at 100%.

I'm attaching an image of top so you can see what's doing it:

btw, im on DEBIAN 8.

[image: htop screenshot]

There is screen without mysql process, just check screenshot.

[image]

MYSQL TUNER SCREENSHOT.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FThBN.png

Comment: How many CPUs does your system have? Are you sure there's a problem? What is the problem, exactly? What is the DB doing? What CPU usage would you expect?

Comment: 4 cpu, 100%, MYSQL is taking 200% cpu instead of 20% normal.

Comment: So it's using 50% of available CPU (200% means 2 out of 4 cores used at 100%). Do you notice any actual problem? Is the machine slower than normal? What makes you think there is a problem here? I am not saying there is no problem, I am just trying to understand what symptoms you see.

Comment: Is this connected to something world-visible? Unusual behaviour can be caused by somebody doing sql injection attacks (though they'd not typically use something that gets noticed, but not all attackers are smart).

Comment: @terdon It's using 100% of the whole CPU (400%) as you can see on the screen. We don't know what the problem is, only those workers but that didn't fix anything. It's just running normal, then jumps to 100% CPU and nothing works.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I don't think that someone is attacking us, we even changed our VPS to prevent these problems, but it didn't fix anything. Phpmyadmin is set to IPs only, so that can't be the problem i think. But i can be wrong, you never know.

Comment: @AdamČech you should check out this [post](https://serverfault.com/a/170546/458184). Try figuring out if all the threads are related. You may need to find out why your application is running so many queries, and how to optimize mysql if all of those queries are legitimate. I would also note that if the application and other traffic patterns to your site are the same as before.

Comment: Added mysql tuner screenshot. Really don't know what is doing this.

Comment: Actually when i try to connect to mysql on 100%, it says that there are too many connections - about 150, normal is around 8.

Comment: You need to analyze what those connections are what they are doing.  Start by looking at the output of `mysqladmin processlist` (`SHOW PROCESSLIST` from within `mysql`).  Check if you have some processes running crazy queries or sleeping.  Also check that the connections are coming from where you expect them to come from.